# Oracle DB Remote directory

Tags: oracle, directory

I have different servers for oracle DB and Application Server and now i I want to create a directory in the oracle DB and under path i want to mention the application server location so that it can be retrieved by application side. Can it be possible to do that.

in Application server there is oracle client installed.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the **database server** have a mapping to the application server directory? That is, if you open an OS terminal session (shell, cmd) on the DB server can you see the remote directory? If the answer is "No" then you need to remedy that. This is a system admin / network question, not a programming one. Bear in mind that sharing drives is a problem in some organisations, especially in production environments, so make sure you check any relevant security policies.

Comment: If you're talking about a directory *object* in the Oracle database that references a remote directory on another server, then no, this isn't possible. Oracle requires that directory objects point only to local directories on the DB server. To share a directory referenced by an object in the DB you'd have to make a local directory on the DB server shareable to the application server, but file sharing like that from a DB server is generally considered a poor security practice. What problem are you trying to solve with this architecture, exactly?

Comment: @pmdba, thanks for the reply. i want to generate a file in the application server using UTL_FILE package . As you said it would be better to generate in DB and share the path to application to access read only.